# Strange code displays when extracting data from an Access Database - I'll explain

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare 1 paragraph of text from an Access database to another paragraph in the same database. I run a loop that does this, when it finds a match; it displays the two paragraphs (1 on top of the other) into a `Richtextbox` on a `Windows Form`.

For each match, it creates a space between the paragraphs using vbnewline. I run this code in a backgroundworker so I can watch the text fill the box. If the database `paragraph` or `row = N/A` then that row is skipped. So I should only see paragraphs. I do get some paragraphs but I also get this

```
<div><font color=black>N/A</font></div><div><font color=black>N/A</font></div>
```

and it is repeated over and over until another paragraph is displayed. Then repeats. I don't understand this as I have no font code written for this sub.

Does passing N/A from a database to my program cause conflicts and I'm unknowingly creating this text to appear?

At first I thought adding a newline was my issue and tried using environment.newline and vbcrlf but that did nothing. I also tried using a different control but I get the same result. I then attempted to generate a report into a pdf using itextsharp 5. While the report generates I still get this extra code. I cannot show any images of the reports due to sensitive information. Any help or suggestions would be great and I can provide more info if needed.

```
'this is an example of what I'm trying to do, essentially two connections are 'open so I can find text that was clearly copied and pasted.
 Command1 = New OleDbCommand
            ds1 = New DataSet
            Connection1.Open()
            Command1.Connection = Connection1
            Command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Command1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Note_Session_Contents WHERE [Provider]=? ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Provider]"
            Command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Provider", provider)
            da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(Command1)
            da1.Fill(ds1, "Note_Session_Contents")
            If ds1.Tables("Note_Session_Contents").Rows.Count > 1 Then
                For Each row1 As DataRow In ds1.Tables("Note_Session_Contents").Rows
                    If Not row("ID") = row1("ID") And Not Session4 = "N/A" Then
                        If row1("Session1") = Session4 Then
                            paragraph.add(Session4 & vbCrLf & row1("Session1"))
                        ElseIf row1("Session2") = Session4 Then
                            paragraph.add(Session4 & vbCrLf & row1("Session2"))
                        ElseIf row1("Session3") = Session4 Then
                            paragraph.add(Session4 & vbCrLf & row1("Session3"))
                        ElseIf row1("Session4") = Session4 Then
                            paragraph.add(Session4 & vbCrLf & row1("Session4"))
                        End If

                    End If
                Next
                Connection1.Close()
End if

 Dim document As New Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate, 25, 25, 30, 1)
        Dim fs As FileStream

        fs = New FileStream("C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Fraud.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)
        document.Open()
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY)
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8)
        'cb.BeginText()
        Dim image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("\\mypc\something$\Lexington\Lexington\LetterHead.jpg")
        Dim imgCell1 As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell()
        imgCell1.AddElement(New Chunk(image, 0, 0))
        image.ScaleAbsolute(800.0F, 85.25F)

        document.Add(image)
        document.Add(paragraph)
        document.Close()
        fs.Close()
        writer.Close()
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line where your code says `And Not Session4 = "N/A"`.  Do any of them have Session4 as "N/A" with extra padding or line-breaks or something?  Could you also try putting paren around `(Not row("ID") = row1("ID"))` sometimes `Not` does unexpected stuff. (like Not the whole statement instead of just the stuff before `and`)

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I tried your suggestions but unfortunately I am still receiving the same issues. I am not using any extra padding. I think I'm gonna try changing the N/A to something like 0 to tell the system to skip over it. Thank you again.

Comment: I would recommend setting a breakpoint on the line where it checks for "N/A" and step-debug over the next lines to see if the logic is doing something that you didn't expect. It is the only explanation that I can see which would explain the issue that you are having.  The text decorations (HTML) are being added by your PdfWriter library. Focus on eliminating the unwanted N/A values which are slipping past your logic/filtering.